# Mapping an external 2d array to another 2d array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/donovandigital/zwz6W/) was intended to create a 2d array of objects which would allow me to access any of the objects (the "clips") by banks[a][b], where [a] was a "bank" and [b] was a "clip". Works perfectly as - is, unfortunately this code is meant to look at some external files and see their properties. These files are already organized in an "array" based on some of their properties. Originally I was told this would be an 8x8 array, however now it turns out that this would be a 16x32 array and the requirements specify banks composed of 4x2 selections from the array.

In other words,

```
banks[0][0].track = 0
banks[0][0].slot = 0
banks[0][3].track = 3

banks[0][3].slot = 0
banks[0][4].track = 0
banks[0][4].slot = 1

banks[0][7].track = 3
banks[0][7].slot = 1
banks[15][0].track = 0

banks[15][0].slot = 31
banks[15][3].track = 3
banks[15][3].slot = 31

banks[16][0].track = 3
banks[16][0].slot = 0
banks[16][4].track = 3

banks[16][4].slot = 1
banks[63][0].track = 11
banks[63][0].slot = 30

banks[63][4].track = 11
banks[63][4].slot = 31
```

I need to iteratively create a 64x8 2d array of "clips", but at the same time set the above properties of those clips as shown. It seems clear that the relevant math belongs in the clip object. However, I can't see the math yet. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `banks[a][b]` is itself a "clip," then why does `banks[a][b]` have a `clip` property? Also, why does the example here have the `clip` property but the sample code you linked does not? Also it's not clear (to me, at least) exactly what your question is.

Comment: Edited to conform with your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need this:

```
var theirBanks = [[...], [...], ...]; // 16*32 array of Clip objects

var x = 2; // reduce outer array to one of half length
var y = 4; // reduce inner arrays to one of fourth length
function reduce(sel) {
/* gets: a 2*4 selection of clips from theirBanks
returns: a new clip for banks */
   ... // not sure how you want this to be done
}

var banks = new Array(theirBanks.length / x);
for (var i=0; i<banks.length; i++) {
    banks[i] = [];
    for (var j=0; j<theirBanks.length/y; j++) {
        var selection = [];
        for (var k=i*x; k<(i+1)*x; k++)
            selection.push(theirBanks[k].slice(j*y, (j+1)*y));

        banks[i][j] = reduce(selection);
    }
}
// banks is now a 8*8 array
```

The script builds 2*4 selections from the (two-dimensional) array, lets you reduce them to a new object and returns the new, smaller (two-dimensional) array.